# Как найти все строки между двумя другими строками?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

```
import re 

html = 'hellodasfadsfgoodbyehellodasfadsfdgdfsggoodbye' 

result = re.search('hello(.*)goodbye', html) 
print(result.group(1))
```

У меня есть строка, и я хочу в ней найти все другие строки между *hello* и *goodbye*. Но вместо этого я получаю одну строку от первого hello до последнего goodbye.

Что сделать чтобы получился список?

Comment: Что значит "все другие строки"?

Comment: Я пытаюсь получить все куски, от hello до ближайшего goodbye.

Comment: Попробовал findall, но он тоже только одну строку в списке возвращает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае будет проще просто убрать все лишние слова

```
html = 'hellodasfadsfgoodbyehellodasfadsfdgdfsggoodbye'


result = html.replace("goodbye", ' ').replace("hello", ' ').split()
print(result) # ['dasfadsf', 'dasfadsfdgdfsg']
```

Answer (score 3):

Нашел решение, надо было просто заменить `hello(.*)goodbye` на `hello(.*?)goodbye` и использовать `re.findall`!!